# Winston Memory leakage Issue in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have created a winston logger service and using the same service in different controller in NODEJS with winston DailyRotateFile.

```
var transport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
  filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
  dirname: './logs',
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
  zippedArchive: true,
  maxSize: '10m',
  maxFiles: '14d'
});
```

and using the same transport in winston.createLogger

```
switch ((process.env.NODE_ENV || '').toLowerCase()) {
  case 'production':
    production = true;
    logger = winston.createLogger({
      transports: [
        transport
      ],
      format: combine(
        label({ label: 'UTILITY_SERVICE' }),
        timestamp(),
        myFormat
      ),
      exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
    })
    break;
  case 'test':
    // Don't set up the logger overrides
    return;
  default:
    logger = winston.createLogger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        transport
      ],
      format: combine(
        label({ label: 'UTILITY_SERVICE' }),
        timestamp(),
        myFormat
      ),
      exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
    })
    break;
}

module.exports = logger;
```

But after using the winston in controller it's  memory size goes very high.

[image]

Is there any memory leakage in winston itself.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: I noticed the same behavior and in some cases it even trigger our autoscaling and brought down our instance in dev (only 1GB of memory and really small CPU).